# Kotlin short-cut to assign value to variable using stream function or other

Tags: kotlin

`for (i in 0 until result.size){                                                result[i].config= addConfig(taskNames!![i],processKeys!![i]) }`

Here result is a list of class which has datamember config and tasNames and processKeys are list of string.
Is there a way in kotlin to map result.config with respective taskNames and processKeys without using traditional loop and mentioning length of result.I am new to kotlin.

```
class Process {
var processKey: String? = null
var task: List<Task>? = null}

class Task {
var taskName: String? = null
var processVariables: List<ProcessVariable>? = null}

class ProcessVariable {
var name: String? = null
var label: String? = null
var applicableValue: List<String>? = null}
```

Result is already present with datamember config pf type ProcessVariable

Comment: whats the output needed? explain clearly

Comment: As Shalu indicates, it's hard to know without knowing more about the types you're dealing with.  Do the objects in `result` have properties other than `config`?  Also, will `result`, `taskNames`, and `processKeys` always be exactly the same size?  (The use of `!!` is a code smell…  As is parallel arrays.  Depending where `taskNames` and `processKeys` are generated, it might make more sense to combine them into a proper object — which you might be able to `map()` straight into a result.)

Comment: I have added the details.Yes result  have other properties.result is a class ,taskNames and processKeys are list of taskName and processKey and corresponding ProcessVariable is to be added to result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to combine 3 lists.
So iterating over the lists may be easier to understand than some clever way of list transformations.

You can get rid of the traditional for loop, so you don't need to calculate the size of the loop:

```
result.forEachIndexed { 
    i, resultData -> resultData.config = addConfig(taskNames[i], processKeys[i])
}
```

If you want to combine two lists, you can use the `zip` method:

```
val configList = taskNames.zip(processKeys) {tsk, prc -> addConfig(tsk, prc)}
```

In your example, the result-object was already existing. Maybe it is easier to create new result-objects:

```
val results = configList.map { 
    Result(config = it)
}
```